# How do you find Taylor series and radius of convergence for $\sqrt{x}$?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

How do you find interval and radius of convergence of $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ at $x=1$

Comment: If you show some work, it is much more probable that you will lure somebody into answering... more so if the question looks like homework.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sqrt{x} = [1+(x-1)]^{1/2}$$

Expand for small values of $|x-1|$; it is a binomial series with the radius of convergence being $1$.  That is, such a series is valid for $|x-1| \le 1$, or $x \in [0,2]$.